# Array of JSON elements to Rails server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, curl

I have an Android application that communicates with a Rails 4 server through HTTP messages.

My server's database has a table `room_entries` that has 3 fields

- name : string
- macaddress : string
- signal : int

Right now I want to send data (JSON) from the Android app to the server, but in most cases I'd want to send more than one `room_entry` at a time.

I'm testing the REST API of the server with `curl` and it is OK when I try do send a POST HTTP message with just **one** `room_entry`, like this:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"room_entry": {"name": "room1", "macaddress": "someaddress", "signal": 10}}'  http://localhost:3000/room_entries
```

The problem is that when I want to send **more than one** `room_entry` at a time, using an array, it adds an empty object (with all fields being NULL) in the database.

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"room_entry": [{"name": "room1", "macaddress": "someaddress1", "signal": 10}, {"name": "room2", "macaddress": "someaddress2", "signal": 40}]}'  http://localhost:3000/room_entries
```

Reading other questions and answers, I've come to the idea that this is a **permit** problem in my controller. There are many examples in how to pass an array of a specific attribute but not about how to send an array of the object itself, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: We need controller's code to help here :/

Comment: @iMacTia the controller's code is the generic one, created with a scaffold.

Comment: Then the problem is simply that the generic scaffolded controller doesn't manage multiple creation with a single call. Do you really NEED this feature (I can show you how to create a method that do this) or you we're just wondering why it was't working? Keep in mind that usually creation is done one item at a time.

Comment: I need to do it. I know that it's not working because my controller is generic, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert more than one record with a  single call, you can do both: create a new method specific for this or modify the existing one and make it working with an array as input.
Here is the second one :) I'm sure you'll prefer it.
First of all, you have to modify the helper methods, so take the generic scaffolded implementation of room_entry_params and change it:

```
def custom_room_entry_params(par = {})
    par.permit(:name, :macaddress, :signal)
end

def room_entry_params #this is the default one, without parameters
    custom_room_entry_params(params.require(:room_entry))
end
```

And in your create action:

```
def create
    if params[:room_entry].is_a? Array # In case you pass more than one room_entry
        params[:room_entry].each { |re| RoomEntry.create(custom_room_entry_params(re)) }
    else
        RoomEntry.create(room_entry_params) # The default behavior, only one room_entry
    end
end
```

Now, you should be able to do both:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"room_entry": {"name": "room1", "macaddress": "someaddress", "signal": 10}}'  http://localhost:3000/room_entries
```

and

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"room_entry": [{"name": "room1", "macaddress": "someaddress", "signal": 10}, {"name": "room2", "macaddress": "anotheraddress", "signal": 20}]}'  http://localhost:3000/room_entries
```

Unfortunately I can't test it right now, so if you get any error just let me know if you can't fix it :)

Comment: It works, just correct `room_entry_parameters` in the create action. It should be `room_entry_params`. Thanks :)